# C++ MySQL driver->Connect vs2017 no symbol loaded

Tags: c++, mysql

When i'm trying to connect to MySQL database there is no errors,but connection is not done.

```
driver = get_driver_instance();
con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306","username","password");
```

driver and con equals to:

```
"0x006b51f8 Information not available, no symbols loaded for mysqlcppconn-7-vs14.dll"
```

I also changed password and it throws exception when I connect to db. It seems connection is good, but this variables can't read data correctly.

[This is image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kngU9.png)

Comment: Maybe you have the chance to compile a new connection driver... also there is a newer version: [link](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/cpp/8.0.html) hope this helps

Comment: @KerimYagmurcu i have everything new for 32bit project, but i don't know how to solve that problem

Answer (score -1):

The "no symbols loaded" just means your debugger does not have access to debug symbols for the driver DLL. This is normal.

To find out why your connection is not succeeding you should wrap the code in an exception handler and handle any SQLExceptions thrown.

```
    try
    {
        sql::Driver *driver = get_driver_instance();
        sql::Connection *connection = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "username", "password");

        // Use connection here
    }
    catch (sql::SQLException &e)
    {
        std::cout << "MySQL connection error: " << e.what() << std::endl;

        // Handle exceptions here
    }
```

Comment: Why do you think the connection is not good? What is not working? Edit your question to show the code after the connection is made, and where it is failing.

Comment: i thought that was connection problem, but when i tried wrong parameter exception occurred. That means connection is good, but mysqlcppconn-7 can't translate data correctly or something like that. Can u help me with that?

Comment: @Giorgi If you update your question with the code that is throwing the exception and the actual exception received, I (or someone) can try to help.